# Safer purrr::map2 for lists with names out of order

Tags: r, purrr

This is a question for which I've written failsafes in my code before, but I'm wondering if there's something more straightforward that I've missed.

I sometimes have 2 (or more) lists that contain different types of information that need to work together with a function such as `map2`—think a named list of `ggplot` objects and a named list of file paths for saving output of each. Is there a way built-in or easily added to a piped workflow to make sure list items are matched by name rather than by position?

Consider a simple example:

```r
library(purrr)

evens <- list(a = 2, b = 4, c = 6, d = 8)
odds <- list(a = 11, d = 9, c = 7, b = 5)
```

`map2` returns a list with the same names as the *first* list, and iterates by position. So the fact that items `b` and `d` are switched in `odds` isn't addressed, and these two calls come out with different results:

```r
map2(evens, odds, function(l1, l2) {
  paste(l1, l2)
})
#> $a
#> [1] "2 11"
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] "4 9"
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] "6 7"
#> 
#> $d
#> [1] "8 5"

map2(odds, evens, function(l1, l2) {
  paste(l1, l2)
})
#> $a
#> [1] "11 2"
#> 
#> $d
#> [1] "9 4"
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] "7 6"
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] "5 8"
```

What I've done in the past is to instead use `imap` and use the names of the first list to extract the appropriate item in the other list, but that means no longer having that second list in my function arguments:

```r
imap(evens, function(l1, name) {
  paste(l1, odds[[name]])
})
#> $a
#> [1] "2 11"
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] "4 5"
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] "6 7"
#> 
#> $d
#> [1] "8 9"
```

If I want to feel like I'm operating more evenly over both lists, I could order them each by name, but this feels clunky:

```r
map2(
  evens[order(names(evens))],
  odds[order(names(odds))],
  function(l1, l2) paste(l1, l2)
)
# same output as previous
```

Or clunkier still, make a list of the two lists, order them each in another `map`, then pipe that into `pmap` since it takes a list of lists:

```r
list(evens, odds) %>%
  map(~.[order(names(.))]) %>%
  pmap(function(l1, l2) paste(l1, l2))
# same output as previous
```

Ideally, I'd like to combine the safety of the `imap` option with the cleanliness of `map2`.

Comment: Maybe use something like `transpose(lst(odds, evens))` and use a standard `map` on top ? Or set your paths as attributes of your ggplot objects, if this is your use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write a helper function to clean it up

```
namemap <- function(.x, .y, .f, ...) {
  n <- order(unique(names(.x), names(.y)))
  map2(.x[n], .y[n], .f, ...)
}
namemap(odds, evens, paste)
```

Basically there's no primitive in `purrr` that will do this automatically for you. And when it's this easy to do, there doesn't seem to be much point.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I'm often wary of just writing helper functions—don't want to lose them in the ether of R scripts. But since I've already written 2 packages of utility functions for work, this is probably the safest and most sustainable way to go.

Answer (score 5):

We can do

```
library(tidyverse)
map2(evens, odds[names(evens)], str_c, sep=' ')
#$a
#[1] "2 11"

#$b
#[1] "4 5"

#$c
#[1] "6 7"

#$d
#[1] "8 9"
```

---

If both the `list` names are unordered, loop through the `sort`ed `names` of one of the `list`, extract both the elements and concatenate

```
map(sort(names(evens)), ~ str_c(evens[[.x]], odds[[.x]], sep= ' '))
```

---

Or create an identifier for the `order`, then `order` the `list` elements in both the `list` and concatenate with `map2`

```
i1 <- order(names(evens)) # not sure if this should be avoided
map2(evens[i1], odds[i1], str_c, sep=" ")
```

Comment: I like the solutioin of just subsetting one to the names of the other. If you use `order` you'll get deceptive results if one list has a name not in the other list

Comment: @IceCreamToucan  There are some `what if`s conditions based on the example.  It could be a bit complicated if the example changes

Answer (score 5):

`bind_rows` matches the names, so you could `bind_rows` and then `map` (although this imposes additional constraints on what's in the lists)

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(evens, odds) %>% 
  map(paste, collapse = ' ')

# $`a`
# [1] "2 11"
# 
# $b
# [1] "4 5"
# 
# $c
# [1] "6 7"
# 
# $d
# [1] "8 9"
```

Answer (score 2):

`transpose()` seems to be doing this (matching by name). Though <s>it's not documented</s> (*edit:* the explanation of the `.names` arg gives context, and there are examples), and the documentation appears to be inaccurate in places (`purrr` v. 0.3.1).

> It's called transpose because `x[[1]][[2]]` is equivalent to `transpose(x)[[2]][[1]]`.

^ seems to be inaccurate since in this instance, `list(evens, odds)[[2]][[4]]` is `5` and `transpose(list(evens, odds))[[4]][[2]]` is `9`.

Also

> Note that transpose() is its own inverse, much like the transpose operation on a matrix. You can get back the original input by transposing it twice.

is not entirely accurate, but we could use that to our advantage:

```r
list(evens, odds) %>% 
  transpose() %>% 
  transpose()
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$a
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[1]]$b
#> [1] 4
#> 
#> [[1]]$c
#> [1] 6
#> 
#> [[1]]$d
#> [1] 8
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$a
#> [1] 11
#> 
#> [[2]]$b
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> [[2]]$c
#> [1] 7
#> 
#> [[2]]$d
#> [1] 9
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

OP's first example (*"think a named list of ggplot objects and a named list of file paths for saving output of each."*) could look like:

```r
  list(paths, plots) # or list(filename = paths, plot = plots) to match args of ggsave
  transpose() %>%
  walk(lift(ggsave))
```

OP's second example could be:

```r
list(evens = evens, odds = odds) %>% # or tibble::lst(evens, odds) but lst() is in the questioning stage
  transpose() %>% 
  map(lift(paste)) # or map(paste, collapse = " ") 
#> $a
#> [1] "2 11"
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] "4 5"
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] "6 7"
#> 
#> $d
#> [1] "8 9"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

---

*note:* I haven't checked if there exists a Github issue about this behavior, nor do I know if there is any likelihood this will change, or gain an additional argument for finer control.

Answer (score 1):

If list names are only partially overlapping, the following modification of @MrFlick 's answer can be used. The applied function must ignore NULL parameters:

```
namedmap2 <- function(.x, .y, .f, ...) {
    set <- unique(c(names(.x), names(.y)))
    lst <- map2(.x[set], .y[set], .f, ...)
    names(lst) <- set
    lst
}
```